# TensorFlow - Tensor Reshape

Tags: tensorflow

I'm using TensorFlow and I have the following matrix:

```
U2 = tf.constant([[1,3],[0,1],[1,0]],dtype=tf.float32)

[[ 1.  3.]
 [ 0.  1.]
 [ 1.  0.]]
```

What's the easiest way to reshape this matrix so that it results in the tensor:

```
tf.constant([[[1,1],[0,0],[1,1]],[[3,3],[1,1],[0,0]]],dtype=tf.float32)

[[[ 1.  1.]
  [ 0.  0.]
  [ 1.  1.]]

 [[ 3.  3.]
  [ 1.  1.]
  [ 0.  0.]]]
```

Answer (score 1):

This is one quick way to create the first submatrix using TensorFlow API:

```
U2 = tf.constant([[1,3],[0,1],[1,0]],dtype=tf.float32)
first_col = tf.unpack(U2, axis=1)[0]
repeated_cols = tf.tile(first_col, [2])
repeated_cols = tf.reshape(repeated_cols, [3,2])
```

Which would create

```
[[ 1.  1.]
  [ 0.  0.]
  [ 1.  1.]]
```